# Handling socket error with try, except [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying catch the exception but the script continues and outputs `none` when something goes wrong with the proxy connection such as `Socket Error: Socket error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` for the expiration date of google

```
import socket
import socks
import whois
import requests
try:
    r = requests.get('http://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?protocol=socks5&maxCheckPeriod=3600').json()
    socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, r['ip'], int(r['port']))
    print(r['ip'], int(r['port']))
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    w = whois.whois('google.com')
    print(w.expiration_date)
except Exception as msg:
    print(msg) #never actually prints this
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing? What if you remove the `try` block?

Comment: @PaulRooney what I mean is the whois will execute but if the pipe breaks midway through, it doesn't return the real result, it instead returns `None` but it may in fact not be `None`

Comment: The actual exception thrown is from `socks`, as a result of you monkey patching `socket`. See [here](http://pastebin.com/5qdFNMKB) for full text. The line you say *'doesnt print'* does print, that is the message text you are quoting in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To catch socket exceptions you need to catch `OSError` exceptions.

Following code will work as expected:

```
import socket
import socks
import whois
import requests

exitcode = 0
try:
    r = requests.get('http://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?protocol=socks5&maxCheckPeriod=3600').json()
    socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, r['ip'], int(r['port']))
    print(r['ip'], int(r['port']))
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    w = whois.whois('google.com')
    print(w.expiration_date)
except OSError as msg:
    print(msg)
```

---

Also you may use another version of this script. It will return an appropriate exit code as result of script execution:

```
import socket
import socks
import whois
import requests

exitcode = 0
try:
    r = requests.get('http://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?protocol=socks5&maxCheckPeriod=3600').json()
    socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, r['ip'], int(r['port']))
    print(r['ip'], int(r['port']))
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    w = whois.whois('google.com')
    print(w.expiration_date)
except OSError as msg:
    print(msg)
    exitcode = 1

exit(exitcode)
```

Comment: this still doesn't make it work unfortunatly.  Tried both versions, if there is any socket error it still continues, never actually hit's the `except`

Comment: How do you know that it is continues? Please explain in detail. In particular, please explain in detail, how exactly you use this script. And what packages you are using? (I see that you are importing 'socks' and 'whois' packages, but it can be tens of a variety of packages with this exactly names. And they may be the reason that something is not working.)